# PHP Curl error 2 Failed initialization when executing script from browser

Tags: php, curl

I'm having a weird issue with curl and PHP.

My test code is this:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.publicapis.org/random',
    CURLOPT_PROXY => 'proxy_url',
    CURLOPT_PROXYPORT => proxu_port,
    CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL => true,
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true
)

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
$error = curl_errno($curl);
$errormsg = curl_strerror($error);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump("publicapis", "<br>", $response, "<br>", json_encode($info), $error, "<br>", $errormsg, "<br>");
?>
```

When excecuted on a linux console **php test.php** connected with an ldap user, my code works just fine an retrieves, for example:

```
string(10) "publicapis"
string(4) "<br>"
bool(true)
string(4) "<br>"
string(588) "{"url":"https:\/\/api.publicapis.org\/random","content_type":"application\/json","http_code":200,"header_size":386,"request_size":166,"filetime":-1,"ssl_verify_result":0,"redirect_count":0,"total_time":0.629362,"namelookup_time":0.004174,"connect_time":0.005151,"pretransfer_time":0.47375,"size_upload":0,"size_download":260,"speed_download":413,"speed_upload":0,"download_content_length":260,"upload_content_length":0,"starttransfer_time":0.629316,"redirect_time":0,"redirect_url":"","primary_ip":"proxy_ip","certinfo":[],"primary_port":proxy_port,"local_ip":"local_ip_addres","local_port":local_port_number}"
int(0)
string(4) "<br>"
string(8) "No error"
string(4) "<br>"
```

But when excecuting the script on the browser (**server_url/test.php**), I'm not receiving any response from the curl request and the error number that retrieves is 2 which stands for Failed initialization.

```
string(10) "publicapis"
bool(false)
string(501) " 
{"url":"https:\/\/api.publicapis.org\/random","content_type":null,"http_code":0,"header_size":0,"request_size":0,"filetime":0,"ssl_verify_result":0,"redirect_count":0,"total_time":0,"namelookup_time":0,"connect_time":0,"pretransfer_time":0,"size_upload":0,"size_download":0,"speed_download":0,"speed_upload":0,"download_content_length":-1,"upload_content_length":-1,"starttransfer_time":0,"redirect_time":0,"redirect_url":"","primary_ip":"","certinfo":[],"primary_port":0,"local_ip":"","local_port":0}"
int(2)
string(21) "Failed initialization"
```

I tried debugging with **curl_error($curl)** and I got no info about the error, I also tried verbosing curl using CURLOPT_VERBOSE and CURLOPT_STDERR options and the file si generated properly but with no info inside (using the console php script the file verboses fine).

I tried another php script that uses a shell_exec("curl command") and retrieves the info just fine on browser and console.

Has anyone faced an issue like this?

I leave some versioning info:

PHP

```
PHP 7.0.27 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2019 15:04:22) ( NTS )
```

CURL

```
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.44 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz unix-sockets
```

SERVER

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.7 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
```

Comment: Do you see anything more if you enable PHP errors and warnings?  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  .  Also, is the user the same for when the script and server run?  They might have different network/firewall access thought that seems unlikely since the other script works.

Comment: Yes, I enabled PHP errors and nothing is showed. When running in console is a user distinct than in browser that runs as apache, my guesses goes to enviremont variables or some weird problem with curl php library